# Is there any way to make body part and Signatory part force in one page When use fop to pdf?

Tags: xsl-fo, apache-fop

Currently i use xsl-fo to convert xml to pdf. The pdf contains head, body, Signatory. The problem is sometimes body part is too long will make Signatory part in different page, means head and body part in one page, the Signatory in one new page. It feel weird because one new pdf page only has Signatory.

Is there any way to force make body one part and Signatory in one page? Any advice will be appreciated.

Comment: If you keep it all on one page, the likely result is that the Signatory will overflow past the bottom of the page.  What are you looking to have happen when there is too much text for one page?

Comment: The body overflow part can start in one new page. I means at least a part of body and Signatory in one page.The problem is when print Signatory, the fop will calculate print area in advance, when no enough space, the entire signatory will print at next page.

Comment: Put the signatory in the footer of the first page and allow the body then to flow over if necessary to the second page

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `keep-with-previous.within-page="always"` on the FO generated for Signatory.  See https://www.w3.org/TR/xsl11/#keep-with-previous

Also, do not use a `keep-together` property on whatever FO you generate for the entire body.

I can't suggest much more without seeing your actual FO markup.